# Array or Loops Results

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I'm trying to make a JSON file eventually that will contain all of the results from Google Maps Reviews but I can only get one/latest review to output...

Can anyone help me as to how to make this into an array to get all the reviews?

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

let scrape = async () => {
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({args: ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox']});
const page = await browser.newPage();

await page.goto('https://www.google.com/maps/place/Microsoft/@36.1275216,-115.1728651,17z/data=!3m2!4b1!5s0x80c8c416a26be787:0x4392ab27a0ae83e0!4m7!3m6!1s0x80c8c4141f4642c5:0x764c3f951cfc6355!8m2!3d36.1275216!4d-115.1706764!9m1!1b1');
await page.waitFor(1000);

const result = await page.evaluate(async () => {

let fullName = document.querySelector('.section-review-title').innerText;
let postedDate = document.querySelector('.section-review-publish-date').innerText;
let starRating = document.querySelector('.section-review-stars').getAttribute("aria-label");
let review = document.querySelector('.section-review-text').innerText; 

     return {
        fullName,
        postedDate,
    starRating,
    review
    } 

});

browser.close();
   return result;
};

scrape().then((value) => {
    console.log(value); // Success!
});
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general `document.querySelectorAll` gives you all results and not just the first.
In specific to your use case, what you want to do is getting a handle on ALL reviews first (before processing them).

I checked the url you provided and would start this way (Puppeteer style):

`await page.$$('.section-review-content')` will return a promise that resolves to an array with all reviews as ElementHandles.

Then you loop through the array and operate on every ElementHandle like this:
`await ElementHandle.$eval('.section-review-title', el => el.innerText)`

So for example, inside your **scrape** function you would have (I shortened your scenario a little):

```
...
await page.goto('https://www.google.com/maps/place/Microsoft/@36.1275216,-115.1728651,17z/data=!3m2!4b1!5s0x80c8c416a26be787:0x4392ab27a0ae83e0!4m7!3m6!1s0x80c8c4141f4642c5:0x764c3f951cfc6355!8m2!3d36.1275216!4d-115.1706764!9m1!1b1');
await page.waitFor(1000);

const reviews = await page.$$(".section-review-content");  
for (const review of reviews) {
 const reviewTitle = await review.$eval(
      ".section-review-title",
      div => div.innerText
    );
 console.log('\n' + reviewTitle);
}
...
```

Check out the [Puppeteer API how page.$$](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v1.5.0&show=api-pageselector-1) works.

Comment: Thank you! Question, how could you get an aria-label, since you can't use div.innerText?

Comment: Your div.getAttribute("aria-label") should work fine.